How to save a tensorflow model and use it in a different file?
I want to save my trained model and load it in a different file.
I've tried using
model.save(my_model.keras)
but when I load it in a different file or when I load it after my runtime gets disconnected (Colab notebook), it does not work. Can anyone suggest a different method or explain what I am doing wrong?

If you're using Google Colab, files stored in the runtime can get lost when the runtime gets disconnected. You can instead store your model on Google Drive and load it from there. Here is an example notebook which demonstrates this integration with Google Drive.
